# Django Filtering Articles by Categories

Tags: python, django, filter, categories, article

I'm building a news web site as a part of a task I was given, homework.

I have a "articles.html" template which renders all of my news articles by publish date. 
I added a for loop in the template to loop over the Category model and display Categories as a list.

What I'm trying to do now is to filter my articles by category, so when I click "sports" on the list, my site now displays only sports related articles.

I have read so much online, and I just got confused, I'm supposed to do this today but I'm having a rough day and would appreciate some guidance !

Here are my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from autoslug import AutoSlugField


class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=200, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', default="",
                         always_update=True, unique=True)
    author = models.CharField('Author', max_length=200, default="")
    description = models.TextField('Description', default="")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    article_text = models.TextField('Article text', default="")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    article_image = models.ImageField('Article Image')
    article_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete="models.CASCADE", default="")
    img2 = models.ImageField('Article Image 2', default="", blank=True)
    img3 = models.ImageField('Article Image 3', default="", blank=True)
    img4 = models.ImageField('Article Image 4', default="", blank=True)
    img5 = models.ImageField('Article Image 5', default="", blank=True)
    img6 = models.ImageField('Article Image 6', default="", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from news.models import Article, Category
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class IndexView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'news/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.order_by("-pub_date").filter(is_published=True)[:6]


class CategoryView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'news/categories.html'
    context_object_name = 'category'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Category.objects.all()


def article(request, article_id):

    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)
    context = {'article': article}

    return render(request, 'news/article.html', context)


class ArticlesView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'
    template_name = 'news/articles.html'
    queryset = Article.objects.order_by("-pub_date")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticlesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context


def add_comment_to_article(request, pk):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = article
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:article', kwargs={"article_id": article.pk}))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'news/add_comment_to_article.html', {'form': form})
```

my urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

app_name = "news"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:article_id>/', views.article, name='article'),
    path('articles/', views.ArticlesView.as_view(), name='articles'),
    path('search/', include('haystack.urls')),
    path('<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment_to_article, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    path('category/<int:category_id>', views.CategoryView.as_view(), name="category")
]
```

And the template im trying to render everything in, articles.html:

```
<div class="container">
    {% block articles %}
    <!-- ***************************************** -->
    <ul>
        <li>Categories:</li>
        {% for category in category %}

        <li>
            <h1>{{ category.id}}</h1>
            <a href="#">{{ category.category_title }}</a>
        </li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <!-- ***************************************** -->

    <hr class="hr-style1">
    <h2 class="article-list-title">Article List :</h2>
    <hr class="hr-style2">
    <div class="container list-wrapper">

        {% for article in latest_article_list %}

        <div class="container">
            <div class="well">
                <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="{% url 'news:article' article.id %}">
                        <img class="media-object" src="{{ article.article_image.url }}">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{% url 'news:article' article.id %}">{{ article.title }}</a>
                        </h4>
                        <p class="text-right">{{ article.author }}</p>
                        <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                            <li><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> {{ article.pub_date }} </span></li>
                            <li>|</li>
                            <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i> 2 comments</span>
                            <li>|</li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>|</li>
                            <li>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></span>
                                <span><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Apologies for the messy code, still trying to learn.

Thank you for taking the time to read this !

I'm not asking you to do this for me, an explanation will be enough ! Thanks !

Comment: In what class do you want to filter ?

Comment: Articles I believe, since I need article info to render it based on the results ? I'm honestly not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `get_queryset` method on your `ArticlesView` by passing a filter param as follow:

```
class ArticlesView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'
    template_name = 'news/articles.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticlesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # It would be best to rename the context to categories 
        # as you are returning multiple objects
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Note you do not have to use the article PK you can use any
        # article field just update the template argument accordingly 
        category_pk = self.request.GET.get('pk', None)
        if category_pk:
            return Article.objects.filter(article_category__pk=category_pk).order_by("-pub_date")
        return Article.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
```

In your template you can then update the category links as follow:

```
<ul>
    <li>Categories:</li>
    {% for category in categories %}

    <li>
        <h1>{{ category.id}}</h1>
        <a href="{% url 'news:articles' %}?pk={{category.id}}">{{ category.category_title }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
<ul>
```

Give this a try and let me know if it works

Comment: This is what I get when I click on one of the categories :

ValueError at /news/articles/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'category.id'

Comment: Traceback says :

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /news/articles/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'articles' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['news\\/articles\\/$']

Comment: Remove the leading `/` from your  `article` url and try again: `path('articles', views.ArticlesView.as_view(), name='articles')`

Comment: Still the same error :

ValueError at /news/articles

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'category.id'

Got no clue what could be wrong. :/

Is it saying that category.id isn't an integer ?

Comment: Still the same :/

ValueError at /news/articles/$

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'category.id'

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/articles/$?pk=category.id
Django Version:  2.1.8
Exception Type:  ValueError
Exception Value:  

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'category.id'

Comment: Looks like the declaration in the template was wrong. Only saw your comment now sorry. Change your url back to `'articles'`. In the the `href` change to `pk={{category.id}}`. I will update the answer

Comment: THANK YOU !!! It worked, but for me it only works if i leave the / at the end of articles, so 'articles/'.

Thanks so much for your time and help !

Comment: Ok great, pleasure